# Explicitly set docstring of a method

Tags: python, nxt

I help to maintain a package for python called nxt-python. It uses metaclasses to define the methods of a control object. Here's the method that defines the available functions:

```
class _Meta(type):
    'Metaclass which adds one method for each telegram opcode'

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        super(_Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
        for opcode in OPCODES:
            poll_func, parse_func = OPCODES[opcode]
            m = _make_poller(opcode, poll_func, parse_func)
            setattr(cls, poll_func.__name__, m)
```

I want to be able to add a different docstring to each of these methods that it adds. m is a method returned by _make_poller(). Any ideas? Is there some way to work around the python restriction on changing docstrings?

Comment: You can also pass it into your `_Meta` constructor in the `dict` argument as `_Meta(cls,name,bases,dict={'__doc__':"""docstring"""})` or call `dict.update({'__doc__':"""docstring"""})` before your `super` call. Now you have at least 4 options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For plain functions:

```
def f():  # for demonstration
    pass

f.__doc__ = "Docstring!"
help(f)
```

This works in both python2 and python3, on functions with and without docstrings defined. You can also do `+=`. Note that it is `__doc__` and not `__docs__`.

For methods, you need to use the `__func__` attribute of the method:

```
class MyClass(object):

    def myMethod(self):
        pass

MyClass.myMethod.__func__.__doc__ = "A really cool method"
```

Comment: I tried this on a class method and get an error.  It turns out that on a class method, which I think is what the original question wants, you would want to do:  self.method.__func__.__doc__

Answer (score 3):

You may also use [setattr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr) on the class/function object and set the docstring.

```
setattr(foo,'__doc__',"""My Doc string""")
```