# Python make class function print the docstring of the function it calls

Tags: python, oop, docstring

Is there an easy way to make class methods return the docstring of a function I wrote in a different module when `help(my_classfunction)` is called?

Comment: Can you give an example code what you are trying to do or what the expected behavior should be?

Comment: The docstring is available via `my_classfunction.__doc__`. `help` mostly formats the doc string (and for things like classes, gathers related doc strings as well).

Comment: @Christian I've written a module with functions that will be accessed using class methods. I've written it this way as the module should be portable. In this case, I have a class where the functions in the module have the functionality and are called by class methods (they are just an interface with the module). However, the end user should only interact with the class so I'd like for the user to be able to do help(my_classfunction) or my_classfunction.__doc__ and actually get the docstring of the function in the module, rather than the class method. Does that explain it a bit better?

Comment: @chepner yes, I'm aware of that. Naively, I tried putting the following in the class method, which didn't work: `my_classfunction.__doc__ = my_module.my_function.__doc__` after importing the module

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit deeper, I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931386/explicitly-set-docstring-of-a-method) that solved my problem. Turned out I had to use `__func__` when setting the docstring of a classmethod.
`self.my_classmethod.__func__.__doc__ = my_module.my_function.__doc__` sets the docstring of the classmethod to the docstring of the function it calls.